Declare and use a named set of ICMP types in nftables
Here is a working example on how I currently use an unamed set containing ICMP types:
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

add table filter_4

add chain filter_4 icmp_out_4 {
    comment "Output ICMPv4 traffic"
}

define response_icmp_4 = {
    0, # Echo Reply
    3, # Destination Unreachable
    10, # Router Solicitation
    11, # Time Exceeded
    12, # Parameter Problem
    14 # Timestamp Reply
}

# Block ICMP response from localhost
add rule filter_4 icmp_out_4 icmp type $response_icmp_4 drop

What I want to do is convert this unamed set called response_icmp_4 to a named set.
Here is my unsuccessful attempt to do this:
# Declare named set
add set filter_4 response_icmp_4 { type inet_service }

# Add ICMP type elements
add element filter_4 response_icmp_4 {
    0, # Echo Reply
    3, # Destination Unreachable
    10, # Router Solicitation
    11, # Time Exceeded
    12, # Parameter Problem
    14 # Timestamp Reply
}

Creating the set works but it's refused during rule processing:
# Block ICMP response from localhost
add rule filter_4 icmp_out_4 icmp type @response_icmp_4 drop

With the following error output:

Error: datatype mismatch, expected ICMP type, expression has type internet network service

The error is self-explanatory, but the question is what type should I specify? because type inet_service does not work.
According to docs valid type expressions are ipv4_addr, ipv6_addr, ether_addr, inet_proto, inet_service, mark
It's also possible to specify typeof to auto-derive data type but this doesn't work as well, for ex:
add set filter_4 response_icmp_4 { typeof vlan id }

Which errors with similar error:

Error: datatype mismatch, expected ICMP type, expression has type integer

Which is an odd error because ICMP type IS an integer.
If you can also link to documentation explaining this that would be helpful because I'm not able to find it.

The named set declaration must match the type to compare it to. An ICMP type is not an inet service:
# nft describe inet_service
datatype inet_service (internet network service) (basetype integer), 16 bits

which means a port. Compatible for example with:
# nft describe udp dport
payload expression, datatype inet_service (internet network service) (basetype integer), 16 bits

So the when adding the rule nftables complains with:

Error: datatype mismatch, expected ICMP type, expression has type internet network service


As for figuring out ICMP type, from the rule (payload expression/typeof) icmp type:
# nft describe icmp type
payload expression, datatype icmp_type (ICMP type) (basetype integer), 8 bits

pre-defined symbolic constants (in decimal):
    echo-reply                                         0
    destination-unreachable                            3
[...]

leading to (datatype/type) icmp_type:
# nft describe icmp_type
datatype icmp_type (ICMP type) (basetype integer), 8 bits

pre-defined symbolic constants (in decimal):
    echo-reply                                         0
    destination-unreachable                            3
[...]

This:

add set filter_4 response_icmp_4 { type inet_service }


has to be replaced with:
add set filter_4 response_icmp_4 { type icmp_type; }

or, instead of type using typeof (which is usually matching what's used in the ruleset so easier to figure out, and which can also be used as above directly with nft describe to figure out the equivalent type):
add set filter_4 response_icmp_4 { typeof icmp type; }

